# Turn a link into an HTML entity with exact same functionality

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

I have this link:

```
<%= link_to "+1", video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :method => :post, :remote => true %>
```

but I want to turn its visual appearance to this: ⇑ with the HTML entity `&uArr;`. How can I do this while keeping the link's functionality?

Comment: You want to do this with Ruby, or would a JavaScript solution work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "&uArr;".html_safe, video_votes_path( :video_id => video.id, :type => "up" ), :method => :post, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: cool thanks... is there a way to restyle the link so that it doesn't look blue?

Comment: Look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to and you want to look at html_options, from there you can style it.

Comment: yeah, i could just add a class. I'm inquiring about the CSS that would make it look like text instead of a link.